# Antonym of "summon"

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking for an antonym to "summon". Would "unsummon" be grammatically correct, though it is not found in a dictionary? A contextual example:

> You are a wizard that has the ability to summon minions. Other wizards have the ability to unsummon your minions.

Comment: You cannot *unsummon* in the first place; you have maybe to *undo* a summon.

Comment: (1) If there are wizards in the real world who do summoning, ask one of them the proper word.  (2) If these are only fictional, you can use whatever word you want in your own stories/games ... just explain what it means somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In videogames, the act of canceling someone else's magic is often called "dispelling". I hope this works for you... :)

Comment: In context of the example above, i think this word fits best.

Comment: Why? *Dispell* can indeed mean driving something away, but *dismiss* is a more direct antonym and both it and *banish* are commonly used in terms of magic depending upon whether it is considered necessarily to compel or merely release (consider the Lesser Banishing Ritual of the Pentagram, probably the best known ritual in modern Western magick).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps *[dismiss](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dismiss)* is the word you are looking for:-

1. to direct (an assembly of persons) to disperse or go: I dismissed the class early.
2. to bid or allow (a person) to go; give permission or a request to depart.
3. to discharge or remove, as from office or service: to dismiss an employee.
4. to discard or reject: to dismiss a suitor.
5. to put off or away, especially from consideration; put aside; reject: She dismissed the story as mere rumor.

So other wizard would *dismiss* your minions.

Answer (score 6):

Though it usually refers to exile, [banish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/banish) seems to fit here.

For the example, I would also consider [vanquish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vanquish) as it has a magical feel to it.

Answer (score 1):

*[Disinvite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disinvite#Verb)* (“To cancel an invitation to”) might work if you regard a summoning as an invitation.  However, while *[summon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summon#Verb)* has such a sense (“To ask someone to come; to send for”) it also has a well-known sense  “To order someone to appear in court, especially by issuing a summons”, against which *disinvite* doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As a former Magic player, I'd say that "other wizards have the ability to" counter your summon spell.